# Is there an official ASP.NET MVC reference/example app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm struggling to find a good reference application for ASP.NET MVC. By "reference", I specifically mean an application that flexes all of the framework's features in the Microsoft-sanctioned manner, such as:

- Master pages
- Partial views
- Strongly-typed models
- Authentication
- Custom routes
- etc...

The open source examples that are out there ([CodeCampServer](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/), [SutekiShop](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/)) either add significantly to the base framework or don't use all of the baked-in features.

Comment: If Gordon Bell, ajma, and LukeDuff don't mind, I would like to keep this question open to see what else gets submitted over the next few months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen Rob Connery's MVC Storefront Webcast Series?

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/#MVCStorefrontStarterKit

Source Code:

http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples/

Comment: Maybe I'm just having a bad day at Finding Things on The Internet, but where's the code? I'm not particularly interested in watching 12 hours of video...

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Just FYI to any others -- the source code was removed in Dec 2008, so you need go to a prior commit to see or download it: http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples/SourceControl/changeset/view/17126

Answer (score 2):

I asked more or less the same question here: [What are some projects which are examples of best practices for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499319/what-are-some-projects-which-are-examples-of-best-pratices-for-asp-net-mvc)

As for official, the closest would be Rob Connery's which was mentioned.

Comment: Snap! This looks like it has a lot (if not all) of what I'm looking for... http://www.codeplex.com/TheBeerHouse/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This isn't official but you could check out Kigg:
http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg

It's a sizable Asp.net MVC Digg-clone with some decent code in it. Used on [dotnetshoutout.com](http://dotnetshoutout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the Nerd Dinner MVC reference app: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ for people just starting

Answer (score 0):

While this might be a little late to the show, I believe that the ASP.net team would like people to start using the [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1)  as the official mvc reference example. The Music Store application is using the Razor view engine with Entity Framework's code first approach (also demonstrates database first) along with examples of dependency injection, test driven development, jQuery integration and getting and using NuGet packages.

A second reference example seems to be more on the cutting edge of things and is provided by the Patterns and Practices people. This is called the [Silk Project](http://silk.codeplex.com/) and takes advantage of the latest web standards like HTML5, CSS3 and ECMAScript 5 along with modern web technologies such as jQuery, Internet Explorer 9, and ASP.NET MVC3.

These together would probably show you the newest in ASP.net MVC development along with some pretty neat ideas and examples.